# нечего vs. ничего

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

Up until I started reading through *Russian Review Grammar* by Marianna Bogojavlensky I had only seen **ничего** offered as a translation for the English "nothing." Bogojavlensky's text, however, often uses **нечего** in its example dialogues as in the following sentence:

> Если это так, то я могу чувствовать только жалость к тебе, и мне **нечего** больше прибавить к тому, что я сказал.
>
> Here is the translation the text offers of this sentence: 'If this is so, I can feel only pity for you, and I have nothing to add to what I have said.'

Is the use of **нечего** in this sentence just a simpler way of saying "у меня нет **ничего** больше прибавить... ?" One [thread](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-vs-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE.2253864/) I looked at on Word Reference said that **ничего** stresses a kind of "absolute negative" while **нечего** merely stresses absence. Can this distinction explain the example given above? Yandex's dictionary [defines](https://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/) **нечего** as 'there is nothing to + inf' or as 'it's no good to + inf.' While I can understand how these definitions differentiate the usage of **нечего** from the usage of **ничего** I don't see how this makes "и мне **нечего** больше прибавить..." preferable to "у меня нет **ничего** больше прибавить... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Ничего* along with a verb requires double negation, so it's always about negating actions. But *нечего* is used with a positive form of the verb, and it denotes a non-existence of an object suitable for action.

So

> Я ничего не скажу --> I say nothing; I won't say anything
>   Мне нечего сказать --> I have nothing to say; There's nothing to say
>
> Я ничего не прибавлю --> I won't add anything
>   Мне нечего прибавить --> I have nothing to add

On the matter of "у меня нет ничего больше добавить..." - it's really ugly, no native speaker says so.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is somewhat akin to "there's nothing" vs. "there isn't anything". For example:

> I'll tell you nothing.
>
> Я тебе ничего не скажу.

versus

> I can't tell you anything.
>
> Мне нечего тебе сказать.

Comment: But you have only _ничего_ in both examples, there's no _нeчего_.

Comment: Sorry, corrected.

Comment: Would the second example you've given be better translated as 'There is nothing for me to tell you'? Also, could you comment on the example I've given, specifically why **нечего** is preferable to **ничего** in that example?

Comment: Yes, that would be proper translation. Indeed, "нечего" carries internally the additional sense 'there is (nothing)' as opposed to "ничего"'. The expression with "нечего" is a bit 'less responsible', it refers to some external reason (I can't tell anything because there's nothing I can tell).

Comment: @Alex _ander +1

Comment: As for me, нечего is also used when you need dative case for your "nothing". But I'm not sure if it's true. It just feels like this to me.